# AudioKit: How to change tempo on the fly?

Tags: swift, audiokit, aksequencer

I am new to AudioKit and programming music app. I'm building a metronome app and using AudioKit's AKMetronome. I want to have a feature where a user can specify a sequence of beat patterns with different tempo. But I find it is inaccurate to use apple's DispatchQueue.

I'm thinking of rewriting the metronome using AKSequencer. Is there a way to use AudioKit's sequencer to change tempo on the fly or generate a sequence with multiple different tempo? (Sequencer example: https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/main/Cookbook/Cookbook/Recipes/Shaker.swift)

```
metronome.tempo = 120
let first_interval = 60.0 / 120.0
let switchTime1 = DispatchTime.now() + (first_interval * 4.0)
metronome.play()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: switchTime1, execute: {
    self.metronome.tempo = 200
})

let second_inter = 60.0 / 200.0
let switchTime2 = switchTime1 + (second_inter * 8.0)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: switchTime2, execute: {
    self.metronome.tempo = 120
})
```

**Update:**

I figured out that you can assign a callback function to AKMetronome using AKMetronome.callback. (https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKMetronome.html#/s:8AudioKit11AKMetronomeC8callbackyycvp) You can then update the tempo at the start of a new sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to create a tempo track, which would contain tempo events that when processed change the sequencer's tempo.

This is an outline of what should be done:

1. Create a track to contain the tempo events, using [AKSequencer](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSequencer.html)'s [addTrack](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKSequencer.html#/s:8AudioKit11AKSequencerC8addTrack3forAA0cE0CAA6AKNodeC_tF) method. Connect this track to an [AKCallbackInstrument](https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKCallbackInstrument.html). Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61545391/2679386) on how to connect an AKCallbackInstrument to an AKSequencer track.
2. Add the tempo events to the track, at the time positions where there are tempo changes. As far as I know, there are no standard MIDI events for indicating tempo changes (such as a control change for tempo). But as you will be interpreting the events yourself with a callback function, it doesn't really matter what type of event you use. I explain below how to represent the tempo.
3. Process the events in the callback function and set AKSequencer's tempo to the indicated tempo.

It’s a little difficult to represent the tempo value inside a MIDI event because usually, MIDI parameters go from 0 to 127. What I would do is use a `Note On` event, in the note's pitch I would store `tempo div 128` and in the note's velocity, `tempo % 128`.

This is what your callback function would look like:

```
func tempoCallback(status:UInt8, note:MIDINoteNumber, vel:MIDIVelocity) -> () {
    guard let status = AKMIDIStatus(byte: status),
        let type = status.type,
        type == .noteOn else { return }
    let tempo: Int = note * 128 + vel
    sequencer.tempo = Double(tempo)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this